# Extracting occlusion data for blocks inside a dxf file

Tags: python, cad, dxf, ezdxf

I have a 2D dxf file of the assembly of an electrical distribution board that contains many different blocks.
I have created a script that prints the names of the blocks that overlap.
I want to know if there is as way to extract occlusion data or any other form of data out of the dxf that can be used to determine which block goes above the other.

I was not able to find a way to extract neither occlusion data nor z order from the file